# ionic 3 cordova issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-devapp

After generating a new project using:

```
ionic start my-app blank --type=ionic-angular
```

I tried to run my app on a mobile device using:

```
ionic serve -c
```

I received this error, and the app is no longer responding to their Ionic DevApp

[image]

Comment: Where is the error? These are warnings.

Comment: After running ionic serve -c the Ionic DevApp on iOS is not able to find my running app, even the laptop and the mobile device are connected to the same network.
This happens after I updated ionic to it's latest version

Answer (score 0):

Is Cordova installed on your system?

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: Yes, Cordova and Angular CLI are up to the latest version